# Stopping the operating system command launched from SAS program , if sas fronted stopped forcefully

Tags: python-3.x, stored-procedures, sas

I am using SAS  unnamed pipe to trigger the python script using the SAS prog(its req, cant change) as below :

```
 filename oscmd pipe "python test.py ";
data _null_;
infile oscmd;
input;
put _infile_;
run;
```

So, once we trigger the above mentioned python script from sas prog, not able to kill it ,if it is need to stop using SAS . although , the sas prog stops, it will be still running till execution completes.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Using Linux system

Answer (score 0):

What is your SAS server host machine operating system ?

If you forcefully close a running SAS session while a pipe command is running, and the command is still running after the session dies, you will need to issue a separate operating system command:

- Unix, `kill` or `kill -9` command
- Windows, `taskkill`

To conditionally kill the `python` task from inside the SAS session during the running `DATA _null_` step you could use the `system` function or call routine

```
  if <condition> then rc = system ('taskkill /im python.exe');
```

Comment: Thanks  @Richard,  But how can we capture , that event of forcefully stoping in SAS session  ( i mean that condition to kill the process) , to issue the kill command from inside the sas code.

Comment: I don't think there is a 'I am being killed' event or condition that a SAS program can respond to. Who, how or why is a SAS session being forcefully stopped ? The agency responsible for stopping SAS should also be responsible for stopping child or possibly asynchronous or forked threads -- I am at a loss as to why a killed SAS session does not also kill a filename pipe process.